# SQL H2 Database select digit + alphanumeric char from string

Tags: sql, regex, string, chat

I try to select just the numbers followed by a alphanumeric character

```
5h 1
5h 5 8h 8 12h 10
12h 10 48h 20
5h 1 8h 1 12h 1 24h 1 48h 1 72h 1
5h 1 8h 1 12h 1 24h 1 48h 1 72h 1
```

For example in the second line `5h 5 8h 8 12h 10` I need to remove numbers `5, 8, 10` i.e which are not followed by a character. Result should be `5h 8h 12h`.

I already removed specific chars with:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE (resource, '[^\w\.@-]', ' ' )
```

Comment: You want to extract or replace ?

Comment: doesnt matter, extract 5h,8h,12h or remove 5,8,10

Comment: I mean you wish to replace `5h,8h,12h` with blank or should `h` be left behind ?

Comment: h should be left behind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this regex

`REGEXP_REPLACE (resource, '\b[0-9]+\b', ' ' )`

Use `\\b` if `\b` doesn't work. Am not sure if it will need double escape.

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rD8dQ3/3)**

Comment: i think you misunderstood me Stirng looks like that: "5h 5 8h 8 12h 10" as a result i should have "5h 8h 12h"

Comment: @simplesystems: Please specify what's missing in my solution ?

Comment: your solution removes the number bevore the "h" but i need the number+h

Comment: what i dont need are the numbers without a "h" like 8 and 10 in the example

Comment: @simplesystems: Ohk, Yea I took it other way. Now I edited the answer. Please check. Well use `\\b` instead of `\b` if it needs double escaping.